# How to convert java (Android) crypto params to iOS crypto?

Tags: java, ios, encryption

I am developing iOS app. Inside that app I have to call SOAP service and send encrypted data. To communicate with the SOAP service I have to use the same configuration that is already using Android app. In that app the following code exists:

```
   private static final String ENCRYPTION_KEY_TYPE = "DESede";
   private static final String ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "DESede/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
```

I need to convert that params so I can use them with `CCCrypt` function. I suppose that `DESede` key type corresponds to `kCCAlgorithm3DES`. For algorithm I read that `CBC` is default so I suppose that I have to use `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding`. I also have `iv` key.

Are my presumptions correct?

Comment: I posted an acceptable answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421146/aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-in-ios-objective-c-result-differs-from-android/56178213#56178213.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the keys and iv are **exactly** the correct length.

"DESede" means:
*DES* (Data Encryption Standard) which should not be  used for new work.
*ede* means encrypt, decrypt, encrypt 3DES (Triple DES - 168 bit, 24 bytes) with key usage that is backward comparable with DES (Single DES - 56 bit, 8 bytes), The the key is broken into three keys where the first is used to encrypt, the second to decrypt, the third to encrypt (ede). It is also possible, but non-standard, to use a different sequence of encrypt and decrypt so check that.

Note, the high bit in each byte is parity and generally ignored.

The iv can be problematic because unless static must be transmitted along with the encrypted data, one common method is to pre-pend the iv to the encrypted data.

Padding can also vary, PKCS#7 is the general standard but some implementations such as PHP use a non standard padding. With PKCS#7  the encrypted length will *always* be at least one byte longer than the plain data. PKCS#5 is essentially the same for this type of encryption.

Comment: 10x for the replay. I am very new to iOS and I have a little experience with C and Crypto. I search in the Google and I found [solution](http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1782361/) that returns exact string that I need (I have the correct string from the SOAP service for a given set of params).